como puedo agregar 2 botones y que cuando algune se presione espere a que se termine el ciclo y luego lo leqa y lo envia al lugar deseado

lo que quiero lograr el preionar un boton y luego hacer que se complete el ciclo y al momemto >de leerlo de nuevo al verde correspondiente sumarle y al igual que al rojo cotrario para que asi >el usuario pueda cruzar.
el codigo tiene mas lineas pero esto es lo que he intentado  para el boton para hacerlo >funcionar.
desde ya gracias por su ayuda.

   while (TRUE)
   {  
        Paso1 = input(PIN_D1);
        Paso2 = input(PIN_D2);

        if (Paso1 == 1 && caso1Ejecutado == 0) 
        {
            mpp1 = 1;
            caso1Ejecutado = 1; // Marcamos que el caso 1 se ha ejecutado
        }

        if (Paso2 == 1 && caso5Ejecutado == 0) 
        {
            mpp2 = 1;
            caso5Ejecutado = 1; // Marcamos que el caso 5 se ha ejecutado
        }

        if (Paso1 == 0)mpp1 = 0;
        if (Paso2 == 0)mpp2 = 0;
      



        switch (ciclo)
        {
        case 0:
        {
            if(contB == 0)
            {
                output_low(Vp2);
                output_low(Vb);
                output_low(Rp1);
                output_low(Ra);
                output_high(Vp1);
                output_high(Va);
                output_high(Rp2);
                output_high(Rb);
            }              
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {   
            ciclo = 0; // Reinicia el ciclo
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        {   
            if(contB == 23500)
                    {
                        output_low(Va);
                        output_high(AMa);
                    }
}
break;


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Aprende a usar el sitio. No dupliques tus preguntas... hay un boton [edit] y las preguntas se abren y cierran sin problemas.. no sabemos de que botones hablas, y tu codigo no es claro como para decirte que tenes que hacer. explica tu codigo y lo que queres hacer...

Y si no te registras, tu pregunta se va a perder si perdes el acceso..
